OpenBSD: USB keyboard not detected at boot time
I've got a problem with a USB keyboard on OpenBSD 7.5: At the boot loader's "boot>" prompt it works fine, but apparently it is not discovered by the kernel at boot time. The keyboard appears to be dead at the login prompt. I cannot login without reconnecting the keyboard's cable to another USB port. Even this fails sometimes.
When the keyboard is finally found, these messages appear in the kernel log:
uhidev0 at uhub0 port 6 configuration 1 interface 0 "SINO WEALTH Newmen Bluetooth Keyboard" rev 1.10/30.04 addr 3
uhidev0: iclass 3/1
ukbd0 at uhidev0: 8 variable keys, 6 key codes
wskbd0 at ukbd0: console keyboard, using wsdisplay0
uhidev1 at uhub0 port 6 configuration 1 interface 1 "SINO WEALTH Newmen Bluetooth Keyboard" rev 1.10/30.04 addr 3
uhidev1: iclass 3/0, 13 report ids
uhid0 at uhidev1 reportid 1: input=1, output=0, feature=0
ucc0 at uhidev1 reportid 2: 573 usages, 20 keys, array
wskbd1 at ucc0 mux 1
wskbd1: connecting to wsdisplay0
uhid1 at uhidev1 reportid 5: input=0, output=0, feature=5
ukbd1 at uhidev1 reportid 6: 120 variable keys, 0 key codes
wskbd2 at ukbd1 mux 1
wskbd2: connecting to wsdisplay0
uhid2 at uhidev1 reportid 9: input=0, output=0, feature=255
uhid3 at uhidev1 reportid 10: input=0, output=0, feature=41
uhid4 at uhidev1 reportid 11: input=0, output=0, feature=255
uhid5 at uhidev1 reportid 12: input=0, output=0, feature=255
ums0 at uhidev1 reportid 13: 5 buttons, Z and W dir
wsmouse0 at ums0 mux 0

I know it says "Bluetooth Keyboard", but it is connected via cable, of course. Bluetooth discovery is off.
usbdevs -vv says
pablo# usbdevs -vv
Controller /dev/usb0:
addr 01: 8086:0000 Intel, xHCI root hub
          super speed, self powered, config 1, rev 1.00
          driver: uhub0
          port 01: 0000.02a0 power Rx.detect
          port 02: 0000.02a0 power Rx.detect
          port 03: 0000.0503 connect enabled recovery
          port 04: 0000.02a0 power Rx.detect
          port 05: 0011.02a0 power Rx.detect
          port 06: 0000.0103 connect enabled recovery
          port 07: 0000.02a0 power Rx.detect
          port 08: 0000.02a0 power Rx.detect
          port 09: 0000.02a0 power Rx.detect
          port 10: 0000.02a0 power Rx.detect
          port 11: 0000.02a0 power Rx.detect
          port 12: 0000.02a0 power Rx.detect
          port 13: 0000.02a0 power Rx.detect
          port 14: 0000.02a0 power Rx.detect
          port 15: 0000.02a0 power Rx.detect
          port 16: 0000.02a0 power Rx.detect
addr 02: 05e3:0748 Generic, USB Storage
          high speed, power 500 mA, config 1, rev 12.09, iSerial 000000001209
          driver: umass0
addr 03: 12c9:6001 SINO WEALTH, Newmen Bluetooth Keyboard
          full speed, power 500 mA, config 1, rev 30.04
          driver: uhidev0
          driver: uhidev1

There is no such problem using Linux on the same hardware. A 15+ years old USB keyboard works fine with OpenBSD, so I wonder what's the story with my regular keyboard here?
I have tried to toggle the legacy keyboard options, CSM mode, etc. in BIOS. I tried different ports on the front and back side of the PC, all in vain. There are several reports in the net about keyboard not working at all (even at the boot> prompt), or after login, but this one seems to be unique.
The PC is a HUNSN RJ43, but I have the same problem with an old Zotac O-series PC.
